# How to draw vertical text as labels in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, heatmap

I'm trying to draw vertical labels for the heatmap that I'm working. I'm using the example from http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084. Here is the part of the code that I've changed:

```
    var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
    .data(ife_nr)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return  (i * gridSize);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    //.style("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + '-5' + ")")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize/2 + '-8' + "), rotate(-90)")
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return ((i >= 0) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis");
    });
```

But it appears the labels seems to be stacked on top one another on top of the first grid. How can I edit this code to get the labels correctly displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: first, the `translate` should have a comma separating the values:

```
"translate(" + gridSize/2 + ",-8), rotate(-90)")
```

Assuming that `-8` is the y value for the translate. If you don't have a comma, the value inside the parenthesis should be just the `x` translation (If `y` is not provided, it is assumed to be zero). But even if there is actually no comma and all that `gridSize/2 + '-8'` is just the `x` value you still have a problem, because `number` plus `string` is a `string`. You'll have to clarify this point.

Besides that, for rotating the texts over their centres, you'll have to set the `cx` and `cy` of the `rotate`. Have a look at this demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 100);

var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
 .data(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
 .enter()
 .append("text");
 
texts.attr("y", 50)
 .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 50 + 80*i})
 .text(function(d){ return d});
 
texts.attr("transform", function(d,i){
  return "rotate(-90 " + (50 + 80*i) + " 50)";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```